# How do I access a dynamically loaded element in jquery or javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

Okay here is the scenerio that is bugging me. I need to get the list of all elements within a dom, even the once that are dynamically loaded.

So say for instance a script element is created with

```
var script=document.createElement('script');
script.type='text/javascript';
script.src='somejsfile.js';
    $("head").append(script);
```

and if I do following that:

```
var doc = document.documentElement;
var scripts = doc.getElementsByTagName("script");
for (var idx in scripts)
{
    var s = scripts[idx];
    if (!s.src) continue;
    s = s.src;
    alert(s);
}
```

How come I don't see the dynamically added script? I tried it in Jquery with the same results.

Does anyone know how this can be achieved? perhaps with dom refreshing?

*Just to be clear: All I want is to loop through the dom and find the 'src' attributes of the 'script' elements, even the one that are dynamically loaded.

Comment: It's working when i use the following code `var headID = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);` not when `$('head').append(script);`

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question. I don't have a problem appending it. It get appended and executed fine. I have a problem accessing its 'src' attribute after that.

Answer (score 3):

Did you add it to the dom...?

```
var script=document.createElement('script');
script.type='text/javascript';
script.src='somejsfile.js';

$(script).appendTo("head"); //or body
```

Comment: Yes I did, sorry I forgot to add that to the question. It executes too without a error msg.

Comment: I dint want to paste the whole script, so I took parts of it. 
Doc is just the document.

var doc = document.documentElement;

Answer (score 1):

You need to append the dynamically created script to the DOM somehow first.  Here's a foolproof way:

```
var ref=document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0],
    script=document.createElement('script');
script.type='text/javascript';
script.src='somejsfile.js';
ref.parentNode.insertBefore(script, ref);
```

Comment: I did append it, I just forgot to insert that line with the question. Check the question again. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like NeXXeuS is correct.  You can also append the your new element without jQuery:

```
var newNode = document.createElement("script");
newNode.type = "text/javascript";
newNode.src = "somescript.js";
document.body.appendChild(newNode);
```

Try running it inside the JavaScript console in Firefox or Chrome and you will see the new script get added appended to the body tag in this case.

Comment: I don't have a problem appending the external javascript to the dom. It executes fine too. But if I try to access it once it is appended through the dom, it is not able to find it. 

All I want is to loop through a page of html text and find the 'src' attributes of the 'script' elements, even the one that are dynamically loaded.

Answer (score 0):

You are appending it with jquery, why not look for it with jQuery?

var scripts = $('script')

or even

var scripts = $('script[src]')

Comment: That is why I am worried. It doesn't pull it up. Tried it with chrome, the script executes it, so it must be added to the dom but jquery or javascript doesn't let me find it.